# Custom Module Login

Tags: users

I am trying to write a module in which I have to send a mail if the user enters wrong password three times. In the mail he should have a link to reset his password. What should I write in validation function for failed attempts?
Please guide me.

I got one suggestion you could also just set the variable 'user_failed_login_user_limit' to 3, and add an extra validation function to login which triggers an email when flood control triggers.Please guide me how to do this.

```
/**
 *Implement hook_form_alter()
 *
 */

 function login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
    case 'user_login_block':
      $user_login_final_validate_index = array_search('user_login_final_validate', $form['#validate']);
      if ($user_login_final_validate_index >= 0) {
        $form['#validate'][$user_login_final_validate_index] = 'login_final_validate';
  }
    break;
  }
}

 function login_final_validate($form, &$form_state) {
 //debug($form_state);
  if($form_state['values']['pass'] != 'abc') {
        form_set_error('pass',t('Sorry, there have being three failed login 
        attempts for this account.A link has being sent to reset pass.'));
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think I need to use User Entity to track the attempt not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The User module uses 4 persistent variables to limit the number of attempted logins a user can do: user_failed_login_ip_limit (default to 50), user_failed_login_ip_window (3600), user_failed_login_user_limit (5), and user_failed_login_user_window (21600).
The first two are used before to check if the account with those credentials exists; the last two are used after loading the user account matching the credentials passed in the login form. The first two values set a limit of 50 failed attempts per hour for the same IP; the last two values allow 5 failed attempts every 6 hours.

Considering that the first limit is reasonably high limit to handle the case of only one apparent IP for all users at an institution, you could set user_failed_login_user_limit to 3 and user_failed_login_user_window to 3600 (1 hour). If that is the only change you need, there isn't any need to replace the validation handler for the login form: Just set the value of those persistent variables in `hook_install()`, and eventually check their values in a hook that Drupal executes less or more periodically.